# SED. How to append a previous string to a current?

Tags: sed

I have a file with following strings:

```
1.44 1.12 
disk 1.00 0.15 0.21
1.15 1.08
disk2 0.15 0.13 0.11
```

How to append 1 string to 2. Not 2 to 1. To get like this:

```
disk 1.00 0.15 0.21 1.44 1.12
disk2 0.15 0.13 0.11 1.15 1.08
```

For example with `sed`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed -n 'h;n;G;s/\n/ /;p' file
```

This will

```
h        # save the line in the hold buffer
n        # fetch the next line to the pattern space
G        # append the hold buffer to the pattern space
s/\n/ /  # replace the newline between them with a space
p        # and print the result.
```

Comment: Just wondering: why the `;` before the final `p`? I tested and it works without it. Note my knowledge of `sed` golfing is quite low :D

Comment: You're right that it isn't necessary here -- it's two different meanings of `p` that come to the same thing in this case. `s/foo/bar/p` will print the pattern space if the substitution took place, `p` as a command of its own will print it regardless. Here we know the substitution will take place, so the `;` could be removed. However, in my mind the command `p` conveys the intent more clearly than the `s///p` flag, since the printing is not meant to be conditional.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to join two consecutive lines, you can for example say this in `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR%2 {prev=$0; next} {print $0, prev}' file
disk 1.00 0.15 0.21 1.44 1.12 
disk2 0.15 0.13 0.11 1.15 1.08
```

This stores the odd lines in a variable `prev` and prints it later on together with the even line.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `awk` version if all lines needed starts with `data`:

```
awk '/^disk/ {print $0,p} {p=$0}' file
disk 1.00 0.15 0.21 1.44 1.12
disk2 0.15 0.13 0.11 1.15 1.08
```

---

Some golfing:

```
awk '/^disk/&&$0=$0p; {p=$0}' file
disk 1.00 0.15 0.211.44 1.12
disk2 0.15 0.13 0.111.15 1.08
```